# Automatic report download from a website that requires username and password without having the URL

Tags: javascript, python, download, report

I need to write a script that allows me to automatically download the "Global Key Report" from Tableau Customer Portal without manually logging in and clicking on the link.

Here is the link explaining how to download this report manually: 
http://kb.tableau.com/articles/howto/managing-tableau-product-keys.

I know that there are commands such as wget or similar options to download a file, but I'm not sure how I can use something like wget in this case.

If I know the URI or be able to figure it out, then I can go ahead and figure out about the code. My preference however, is Python or Javascript, which I'm not familiar with.

Sorry if this question seems so weird or simple, but I have minimal experience with writing codes to download files from the web.

I looked at other similar posts, but was unable to understand anything.

Your help is much appreciated in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There may be a way to do it without using an API, but imho it will be complicated. The steps involved would be this:

1. Use the developer tools of your browser to observe the POST request that is sent to the server when you manually download the file.
2. Analyze the request to see how to modify and abstract it.
3. Either write a Bash script that uses wget to download the file OR write a python script to download the file. Bash will be faster and more concise, python will be more complicated but give more flexibility.

I will follow up with some details and pointers and possibly an example. I hope this helps with the general direction right now.

Ok so an update to this answer to explain step 1. As an example I'll download some public airport arrivals data from the Bureau of Transportation Statistics, which can be found at this address: https://www.transtats.bts.gov/DL_SelectFields.asp?Table_ID=236

I use this example because that is how I learned POST-analysis-and-download ingest myself. I'll assume you are using Chrome or Chromium.

1. Go to the URL above.
2. Press Ctrl-shift-i to open developer tools
3. Go to the "Network" tab and tick "Preserve log"
4. On the website, click the "Download" button. You'll be offered a Zip file for download. Also, data will start to appear in the developer tools.
5. Under "Name" click on the entry that is like: Download_Table.asp?Table_ID=236&Has_Group=3&Is_Zipped=0
6. In the section that opens, look at the "Headers" tab. Look for the entry "Form Data". There you can see the details of the request.
7. Click "view source". This will show you the full POST request parameter string that leads to your download.
   8 Write code in Bash using curl or wget, or write a python script that generates a post request for a download using a string with the correct parameters. If needed I'll get into details about that at a later time.

Hope this helps. When I have more time I'll be updating this answer to include an example how to download with Bash / curl.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so since all the answer I got to this question is a negative vote, I'm going to post an answer myself. To download something directly from the web, you need an API, meaning that the publisher website, for instance, should give you coding means or handles so to speak that enables you to connect to the object, data, etc. you want to pull from the web. 
In this particular case, as my luck would have it, there is no designated API to automate the downloading process. 
After doing some research, I realized that Tableau connects to Salesforce to get the data, so I thought the Tableau people might be able to give me API details and it would be something similar to how people automate downloading reports from Salesforce.
I contacted the Tableau support team and they said currently there is no API to automate downloading the all keys report. 
They directed me to something they have created called Web Data Connector, and I am trying to see if I can automate pulling the report through that. 
There are also ways that allow web scraping and pulling the data directly from the HTML table representing it in the webpage using Python. I'm not sure if that's possible, but I'm working on both solutions. Will update this post if I make any progress.